# Алгоритм зависимости выдачи от статистики

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, node.js, математика

Добрый вечер. Прошу помощи в доработке алгоритма. Суть такова: мы имеем базу данных "id", "name", "chance", "counter". В ячейке `counter` хранится количество раз выпадения предмета (сайт типа рулетка). В `chance` хранятся проценты на выпадение (на все предметы в базе в сумме их 100). Нужно сделать выдачу с БД зависимо от шанса и количества выпадений. (Чем больше процент (шанс) на выпадение и чем меньше раз он "выпал" - тем больше шанс на выпадение СЕЙЧАС).

На ночь глядя написал вот такой алгоритм, но он слишком "тупой" и работает так же. Прошу помощи !

## Алгоритм v0.1

```
var bd = { 
    "id": [7, 9, 10, 14], // Primary keys
    "ch": [90, 7, 2, 1], // Chance dropped
    "dp": [0, 0, 0, 0] // Dropped times
}

function SomeMath() {

    var temp = [],
        idshes = [];

    for( var i = bd.id.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

        temp[3-i] = bd.ch[i] * bd.dp[3-i]; // Перевертаем массив с процентами.
        idshes[3-i] = 3-i;

    }

    temp.forEach( function ( el, _x, arr ) {

        arr[ _x ] = [ arr[ _x ], idshes[ _x ] ];

    });

    temp.sort( function( a, b ) { return b[0] - a[0]; } );

    idshes = temp.map( function ( el, _x, arr ) {

        arr[ _x ] = el[0];
        return el[1];

    }); // Отсортировали массивы и узнали наименьшее число. Его берем за нужный предмет.

    bd.dp[ idshes[ idshes.length-1 ] ]++; // Добавляю к этому предмету 1 выпадение.

}

for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {

    SomeMath(); // Вызов ф-и для теста

}

console.log( bd.ch );
console.log( bd.dp );
```

В качестве базы используется Объект `bd`.

## Скриншот результата сортировки

Где верхний массив - проценты на выпадение, а нижний число выпадений для каждого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"Чем больше процент (шанс) на выпадение и чем меньше раз он "выпал" - тем больше шанс на выпадение СЕЙЧАС"* - учтите, что от того, сколько раз подряд у вас монетка выпала орлом, вероятность выпадения решки на следующий раз **не** повышается... А так - берете случайное число до 100, и смотрите - если меньше шанса первого - выпал первый, если больше шанса первого, но меньше суммы шансов первого и второго - второй, и так далее...

Comment: Если у меня, к примеру, на розыгрыше будет самсунг за 10 000 рублей и эпл за 50 000 рублей проценты будут 70 на 30, к примеру опять же. И мне не нужно что бы по счастливой случайности эпл выиграли 3 раза подряд. Должно быть все строго.

Comment: Это совсем другая задача. При "чем меньше выпал - тем больше шанс" вы не гарантированы от "счастливой случайности". Чтобы гарантировать - снимайте выигранный товар с торгов :) И учтите главное - это к вашим формулировкам - при некачественном ТЗ результат обычно ХЗ...

Answer (score 1):

Как указали в комментариях, не нужно учитывать, сколько раз уже выпал этот ID. В больших выборках процент выпаданий будет стремиться к шансу выпасть этому ID. Проверьте сами: (Нажмите «Выполнить код»)

```js
var bd = { 
    "id": [7, 9, 10, 14], // Primary keys
    "ch": [90, 7, 2, 1], // Chance dropped
    "dp": [0, 0, 0, 0] // Dropped times
}
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
  
  rulette=Math.random()*100;//получаем случайный процент
  sum=0;
  pos=-1;
  while (rulette>sum) { //определяем что выпало
     pos++
     sum+=bd.ch[pos]
  } 

  bd.dp[pos]++ // добавляем к счетчику
  
}
 document.write( JSON.stringify(bd))// выводим результат
```

Comment: Да, я это понимаю. Но рандом не нужен. Такого, как например при тесте вашего кода `{"id":[7,9,10,14],"ch":[90,7,2,1],"dp":[899,79,11,11]}` быть не должно. Должна выпадать одинаковая сумма всех процентов. `900, 70, 20, 10`. Это очень важно для моих целей.

Comment: Как бы это выразиться... Похоже, автор вопроса даже сам для себя все еще не сформулировал четко, что именно ему надо...